# How to add timedelta to time

Tags: python

I want to get the time five minutes from a given time. Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> c.video_length
datetime.time(0, 45, 15)
>>> c.video_length + timedelta(minutes=5)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `timedelta` only to `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

(datetime.combine(date.today(), c.video_length) + timedelta(minutes=5)).time()
```